# How to setup ASP.NET MVC Web App to use Client Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-certificates

I'm trying to use Client Certificates to secure my Web App. I'm using the following guide:

https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/25/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-5-working-with-client-certificates-in-a-web-project/

Things I've done:
1. Successfully created my self-signed certificate and installed them
2. Changed code so that a certificate will be checked for when the Web App is run. However, most code changes are required to be done in Program.cs. However, my project doesn't have a program.cs which is why I kept all of the Program.cs code in the Startup.cs file. Now when I run my app locally, nothing loads. The page keeps loading. There is no error message either.

Here's my code:
I have commented out the code and then it works, otherwise it doesn't and just keeps trying to load the page. The developer tools on chrome doesn't show anything either.

startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(CRUDOperations.Startup))]
namespace CRUDOperations
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            /*
            try
            {
                X509Certificate2 clientCert = GetClientCertificate();
                WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
                requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44309/")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("customers").Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception while executing the test code: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            //Console.ReadKey();

        */
        }





        //Method to locate the client certificate
        private static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
        {
            X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            try
            {
                userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
                X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localtestclientcert", true);
                X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
                if (findResult.Count == 1)
                {
                    clientCertificate = findResult[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to locate the correct client certificate.");
                }
                return clientCertificate;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                userCaStore.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StudentApiController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CRUDOperations.Models;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace CRUDOperations.api
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/StudentAPI")]

    public class StudentAPIController : ApiController
    {
        StudentDBEntities dbContext = null;

        public StudentAPIController() {
            dbContext = new StudentDBEntities();
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpPost]
        //Saves a particular student in the database
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveStudent(tblStudent astudent) {
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                dbContext.tblStudents.Add(astudent);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                result = 0;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }

        //Gets all the students from the database:
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpGet]


        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            X509Certificate2 clientCertInRequest = RequestContext.ClientCertificate;
            //X509Certificate2 clientCertInRequest = Request.GetClientCertificate();
            if (clientCertInRequest != null)
            {
                IList<tblStudent> students = null;
                try
                {
                    students = dbContext.tblStudents.ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    students = null;
                }
                return Ok<IList<tblStudent>>(students);

            }
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("ClientCert");
            return Unauthorized(authHeaderValue);
        }


        /*
        public List<tblStudent> GetStudents() {

            List<tblStudent> students = null;
            try {
                students = dbContext.tblStudents.ToList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                students = null;
            }
            return students;
        }

        */
        //For eg a complete route will be: /api/StudentAPI/GetStudentByID/2
        //Edit the student data:

        //Constraint that the studentID needs to be an int
        [Route("GetStudentByID/{studentID:int}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpGet]
        public tblStudent GetStudentByID(int studentID)
        {
            tblStudent astudent = null;
            try
            {
                astudent = dbContext.tblStudents.Where(x => x.StudentID == studentID).SingleOrDefault();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                astudent = null;
            }

            return astudent;
        }

        //Updating the student details:
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateStudent(tblStudent astudent) {
            int result = 0;
            try {
                dbContext.tblStudents.Attach(astudent);
                dbContext.Entry(astudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = 1;
            } catch {
                result = 0;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,result);
        }



        //Delete the student:
        [Route("DeleteStudent/{studentID:int}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(tblStudent))]
        [HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteStudent(int studentID) {
            int result = 0;
            try {
                var student = dbContext.tblStudents.Where(x => x.StudentID == studentID).FirstOrDefault();
                //Attach lets us update only that entity, not every field in the table.
                dbContext.tblStudents.Attach(student);
                dbContext.tblStudents.Remove(student);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = 0;
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong. My project has the following file structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTZCg.jpg

Comment: You've posted code in your Startup class that configures a certificate for a client, but your Startup class is in your web-application. I think you have a misunderstanding about what client certificates are actually for.

Comment: Also, FWIW, most ASP.NET (and ASP.NET Core) environments delegate handling of client-certificates (and server-certificates) to the the webserver that's hosting the application (IIS) or its reverse-proxy (ASP.NET Core), they rarely do it themselves in their own application code.

Comment: My goal was to make use of the code to ask for a client certificate installed on the machine to make sure that a valid client is using the web application. If I wouldn't put that code in the startup class where else would I put it? @Dai